# Dependency error while trying to use dll

Tags: c#, dll, assemblies

I am trying to connect the quantumsoftware winforms components (http://www.quantumsoftware.com.au/Products/WindowsFormsComponents.aspx) to my visual studio 2010 (.net 4) project. The following warning always pops up when I try to use one of the components. Afterwards it results in an error: namespace not found.:

The referenced assembly "QSS.Components.Windows.Forms" could not be resolved because it has a dependency on "System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which is not in the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client". Please remove references to assemblies not in the targeted framework or consider retargeting your project.

Does someone know how I can solve this error. Normally it should be compatible with .NET 2 and higher...

Thanx!

Comment: This seems to be a problem that should be directed to the component authors Quantum Software directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You project is probably targets .Net 4 Client profile and not the full .Net 4. You can change it in Project Settings->Application->Target framework.

To clarify on comment:

The .NET Framework 4 Client Profile is a subset of the .NET Framework 4 that is optimized for client applications. It provides functionality for most client applications, including Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF), Windows Forms, Windows Communication Foundation (WCF), and ClickOnce features. This enables faster deployment and a smaller install package for applications that target the .NET Framework 4 Client Profile.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656912.aspx

Comment: Allright, that seems to be the problem... Whats exactly the difference?

Comment: @VeeWee - I added explanation to the answer.